# How to design the user table in database?

Tags: django, database, web

I want to develop a server side of an app that holds users.
Of course I need a table in database holding the user information.
At first I may write

```
class User(models.Model): # using django models
    userid = ...
    password = ...
```

which gives me a `database table` containing `userid` and `password`.

However, I might want to add some attributes (maybe Credit, Birthday...so on) to each user in the future. I just can't think up all of them right now. And I can't know what attributes I would really need in the future.

How can I deal with it?

Comment: You **must not** write your own code to store passwords.

Comment: Maybe start by reading the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Answer (score 2):

There's already a user table in Django. This table is automatically create when you first apply the migration with 'manage.py migrate' command.

In database schema, this table is listed as auth_user and you can import it into Django with the following command

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Answer (score 1):

Django provides a default model for [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model). you can use it like this.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and as per your second query. you can do so by creating another model and adding a [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) or [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) of `User` model to link it with each user.

```
class Customuserprofile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    credit=models.CharField()
    birthday=models.DateTimeField()
```

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to add some field to the User you can use AbstractUser or AbstractBaseUser model read this that explain the differences and give a example https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#abstractbaseuser